# Обход XSS санитизации

Tags: javascript, xss

Надеюсь кто-нибудь сможет выручить... В чем проблема, в закрытой Bug Bounty программе почти нашел XSS, есть тэг img, а в его src можно встроить что угодно, кроме
' " <> \ и пробела, уже пару часов бьюсь, не могу выполнить JS код, и через svg пытался, и через javascript:, %20 не работает. Уже не знаю, как можно еще попытаться, надеюсь, вы сможете помочь.

Comment: возможно, там в принципе нет уязвимости)

Comment: Обойти бы санитизацию ", получилось бы, но что-то не особо выходит...

Comment: так, как вы ее обойдете?) если она есть, то вы ее не обойдете)